# Can't integrate Spring Cloud Config Server with remote Git

Tags: git, github, spring-cloud-config

I've a simple configuration server with Spring Boot created with the `spring-cloud-config-server` starter.

This is my application.yaml file:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo
server:
  port: 9999
```

This is the code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

If I try to retrieve any configuration (for example invoking http://localhost:9999/bar/default) I got an exception from the config server.
I got the same exception on application startup putting `cloneOnStart: true`.
The exception is `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1`.
I 've also tried with other github repositories with no success.

Everything works fine if I use a local repository like below:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: file:///path/to/config
```

Used versions are:

- OS: Windows 10
- Java 8
- Spring Boot 2.0.2.RELEASE
- Spring 5.0.6.RELEASE

Below the last part of the stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultEnvironmentRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/DefaultRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0 (AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate (DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject (AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject (InjectionMetadata.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues (AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1348)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0 (AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (ConstructorResolver.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0 (AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate (DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument (ConstructorResolver.java:815)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray (ConstructorResolver.java:721)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (ConstructorResolver.java:470)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0 (AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:503)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType (AbstractApplicationContext.java:1198)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorBeansComposite.get (HealthIndicatorBeansComposite.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointConfiguration.healthEndpoint (HealthEndpointConfiguration.java:38)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3f954bb7.CGLIB$healthEndpoint$0 (<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3f954bb7$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8fe54fed.invoke (<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper (MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept (ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3f954bb7.healthEndpoint (<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate (SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (ConstructorResolver.java:579)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0 (AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean (AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.createEndpointBean (EndpointDiscoverer.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.createEndpointBeans (EndpointDiscoverer.java:132)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.discoverEndpoints (EndpointDiscoverer.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.getEndpoints (EndpointDiscoverer.java:116)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.servletEndpointRegistrar (ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.java:45)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f56ec575.CGLIB$servletEndpointRegistrar$0 (<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f56ec575$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$975c2e4b.invoke (<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper (MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept (ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f56ec575.servletEndpointRegistrar (<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate (SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (ConstructorResolver.java:579)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0 (AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType (ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType (ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:213)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans (ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:90)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init> (ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:250)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:237)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup (TomcatStarter.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal (StandardContext.java:5245)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call (ContainerBase.java:1421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call (ContainerBase.java:1411)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring (String.java:1967)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.HttpClientConfigurableHttpConnectionFactory.lookupHttpClientBuilder (HttpClientConfigurableHttpConnectionFactory.java:69)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.HttpClientConfigurableHttpConnectionFactory.create (HttpClientConfigurableHttpConnectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.httpOpen (TransportHttp.java:830)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect (TransportHttp.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch (TransportHttp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp (FetchProcess.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute (FetchProcess.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch (Transport.java:1269)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call (FetchCommand.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch (CloneCommand.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call (CloneCommand.java:200)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.cloneToBasedir (JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:560)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.initClonedRepository (JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:318)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.afterPropertiesSet (JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:249)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.afterPropertiesSet (MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:69)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1765)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0 (AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate (DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject (AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject (InjectionMetadata.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues (AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1348)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0 (AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (ConstructorResolver.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0 (AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate (DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument (ConstructorResolver.java:815)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray (ConstructorResolver.java:721)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (ConstructorResolver.java:470)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0 (AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:503)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType (AbstractApplicationContext.java:1198)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorBeansComposite.get (HealthIndicatorBeansComposite.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointConfiguration.healthEndpoint (HealthEndpointConfiguration.java:38)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3f954bb7.CGLIB$healthEndpoint$0 (<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3f954bb7$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8fe54fed.invoke (<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper (MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept (ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3f954bb7.healthEndpoint (<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate (SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (ConstructorResolver.java:579)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0 (AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean (AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.createEndpointBean (EndpointDiscoverer.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.createEndpointBeans (EndpointDiscoverer.java:132)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.discoverEndpoints (EndpointDiscoverer.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.getEndpoints (EndpointDiscoverer.java:116)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.servletEndpointRegistrar (ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.java:45)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f56ec575.CGLIB$servletEndpointRegistrar$0 (<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f56ec575$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$975c2e4b.invoke (<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper (MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept (ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f56ec575.servletEndpointRegistrar (<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you found solution?

Comment: Had same issue, changed Spring to 1.5 version and it worked. Trying to figure out why it fails under 2.0+

Comment: @MichałSzkudlarek not yet

Comment: If you want test it you can find the code here https://github.com/alessiofiore/spring-cloud-config.git

You can do a test invoking http://localhost:8080/core/default

Comment: Sounds like this issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1028

Answer (score 1):

Create a file name bootstrap.properties and put the URI information there. I have tried and it is working.

```
bootstrap.properties
==================================
server.port = 8888
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo
spring.cloud.config.server.git.cloneOnStart=true
```

You can access them through the URL like
http://localhost:8888/config-server/default/master

[image: access properties like this]

Comment: Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).